# Can I create a background service that always run even if flutter app is not running?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a Background service which is always running even if app is not running in background , so that I can manage different features in my flutter , is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.

1. You can check out [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service). It's a new package.
2. [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) is another package that can help you out.
3. Additionally if you're only planning to execute a task when you get some new information from a remote server, firebase data message can be used too, where you'll run a function upon receiving a data message. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: i tried it but it sends the notification really slow when my app is in background , 

can firebase send notification if the app is not open??

Comment: firebase data messages do work when the app is not open. I don't know about the latency factor though. Btw there's a difference between **firebase data message** and **firebase notification message**.

Comment: what i want is a notification with to action button as we see in whatsapp notification like "mark as read" and "reply" but in my case i want approve and reject option ,

Comment: You could use firebase data message with flutter custom notifications. I don't have much experience with it though.

Comment: firebase cloud  message worked for me , and it sends the notification right on time , thank you for the help

Comment: Glad I could help. 